# Change the PHP binary that should be used from Drush

Tags: drush

I'm on an Ubuntu shared server hosted at pair.com. Their default PHP version is 7.4, but I was able to change it to PHP 8 for Drupal in my .htaccess; Drupal 9 works fine. My composer specifies PHP 8 and Drush 11.

When I run `../vendor/bin/drush`, it thinks I'm using PHP 7.4.

> Composer detected issues in your platform:
>
> Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2". You are running 7.4.28.

In the .bashrc file, I set `DRUSH_PHP` to the PHP 8 binary, but it is still trying to use PHP 7.4.

```bash
export DRUSH_PHP='/usr/local/bin/php8'
```

Is there another way to tell Drush which PHP binary must use?

Comment: When you call `/usr/local/bin/php8 path/to/drush-binary` it works, right?  If so, you can add a bash alias or variable in your script, etc.

Comment: yes, thanks, I just figured that out - works great!